# ! LaTeX Error: File `minitoc.sty' not found

Tags: linux, minitoc

I'm using Fedora 21 as OS and Texmaker to compile my tex files, recently I used minitoc package but I got always the same error !

```
! LaTeX Error: File `minitoc.sty' not found.
```

I tried to install the package using the following command, but it doesn't work !

```
$ su -c "yum install 'tex(minitoc.sty)'"
```

Thanks for your help to resolve this problem.

Comment: The files are on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I am sure that Fedora has no package named `tex(minitoc.sty)`. Even without checking, such a name would violate any sanity-check whatsoever.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but usually it's the command I use to install the .sty package and it works very well ; but now I really can't use minitoc under the Fedora distribution.

Comment: Fedora 21 is end-of-life, time to upgrade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Fedora 22, I had the same problem and solved it by installing the `texlive-collection-latexextra` package.

`$ sudo dnf install texlive-collection-latexextra`

It seems that the most reliable way to be able to compile most tex files is to download all packages.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I was looking for this a longtime ago.